# Run unit tests parallel and then integration tests sequentially

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parallel-processing, visual-studio-2013, integration-testing

I'm wondering how i could run my unit tests in parallel and my integration tests normally.

Consider the following scenario:
I have two projects, one for my unit tests and one for my scenario tests.

Now i can adjust the test settings like described in [this forum](http://ardalis.com/run-your-unit-tests-in-parallel-to-maximize-performance).
But this would affect all my tests right?

So i'd need a way to run my unit tests first with Parallel.testsettings.
followed by running my integration tests normally with the Local.testsettings

Any ideas or workarounds, or am i looking at this all wrong?

Comment: Why don't you want integration tests to run in parallel?

Comment: @sondergard Not the op but unit tests are easy to isolate can have provable thread safety (if you use patterns like IoC for all parameters and mock the inputs). Integration tests have more of a vertical slice of the system and you can't as easily grantee thread safety between two tests (say two tests both try to write to the same entry in a database, in a unit test the database connection is mocked, in a integration test you use a real connection to a test database)

Comment: @sondergard Well imagine i have a function that adds multiple people to the database and then checks if those people have been added and a test that removes all the people from the database and then checks if there are no more people in the database (stupid example). those two contradict each other. and could cause to fail one another.

Comment: Is this for your local machine or for a build machine? if for a build machine, what are you using (ie TC, jenkins, etc)?

Comment: @Nick V having dependencies between tests is a terrible idea, setup should create some data, teardown should clean your db

Comment: @Miau Local machine. And when would you clean your db? after all the tests instead of each test? So i'd have to pay attention to use a different records and create them with each test when testing updating statements or delete statements? well i could do that i suppose just seems like a hassle.

Comment: Well what if you need to open a socket, listen to some upd packets and close on a particular ip/port? People underestimate the need for integration tests to be run sequentially instead of parallel.